# Login popups not working in Facebook App and if popuup blockers are present

Tags: javascript, android, ios, facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk

We have several problems with using the FB JS SDK, and popup blockers or Native App Web Views.

1. FB App has a setting to open websites inside of Facebook app as a webview. - this seems to have a blanket popup ban... so FB.Login() just does nothing.
2. iOS has a default setting blocking all POPUPs - Chrome/Android also has this but its not default.

I find it hard to believe that Facebook is not aware and has a solution to this, as it seems the most-case these days.

Journeys affected.

1. FB Native app user clicks link to our site. Opens in FB WebView - Can't login with Facebook.
2. Safari user has iOS popup blocker turned on - FB JS SDK just doesn't work.
3. PC/Laptop Chrome, as popup blocker turned on - FB Login won't work.

The only way we can see to make this work in a modern mobile landscape is to implement the full Oauth redirect flow.

Surely this is now true FOR ALL Mobile or responsive websites - any of your users could be viewing your site through a Native App Facebook, Twitter, Gmail, Slack, LinkedIn, or any other.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the redirect flows as specified in the FB Advanced section.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow

Its the only way to reliably login or set permissions with FB and Twitter on todays mobile landscape with a myriad of in native-app 'webviews' to display webpages and sites.